# Should you load the user input directly into the normalized table or star schema or a flat table?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a simple app that stores user transactions for an account. My question is where should the user input data be stored to update the UI. Do I first load the input in a flat table and then insert into the normalized table. This way, for UI update I would have to read the flat table. I am also trying to have a reporting functionality, hence, I am planning on user a star schema table for reporting.

As of now, my plan is user data goes into flat table, which is read to update the UI of transactions. Then I will transfer the data to a normalized table. Later run a ETL process for the star schema load for reporting.

I am new in data modeling, so please feel free to correct my errors and suggestions for improvement. My data amount is very little, so in reality speed is not an issue. But I want to model it as if such that it can handle on a large scale data. The table is working, but I want to know the better way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had one android project where I had to collect data and sync them through web service with main server.
Project Manager required that printing data to UI be as fast as possible. So we made SQLite db that suits our needs:

- same database design as db on server for easier syncing data
- flat table for each screen filled by trigger (so UI can query: SELECT * )

Server had:

- normalized design database (with flags and time-stamps for syncs)
- star-schema data mart for reporting

So, our data flow was:

1. Insert/Update/Delete in normalized tables (sync)
2. Triggered Inserts/Update/Deletes to flat-tables
3. Triggered Inserts/Update/Deletes from synced server to star-schema data mart

All transactions are real-time.

Comment: So UI was updated after the sync from the server using the flat tables in the SQLIte DB,correct? For the reports, were they generated on Demand, like summary of current month's transactions requested by the user?

Comment: UI is updating on each flat-table updated. Flat tables are updating on each normalized table updated. Normalized table are updating on user insert/update/delete on the device, or on syncing with server. Yes, from SQLite. Reports was generated on demand, and on schedule it was gone through BI tool.

Comment: Thank you. I understand it now much better.

Comment: I forgot to note that you do not need to have flat tables for UI if you do not have complex SQL queries or you do not have too many rows and calculations. We had some screens with 1000+ rows with, sums, averages, and complex date based joins (ie. Where t1.fk1 = t2.pk and t1.date >= t2.start-date and t1.date <=t2.end-date)